# FFmpeg command for Merge audio with video not working - C#

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg, mp4, wav

I have tried to combine a `video.mp4` file with `mic.wav` as like below. But combined video is not generating.
Command prompt says -

> 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Shall I need to install ffmpeg other than Accord.Video.FFMPEG? If then is it independent for each system the app execute? 
Please help to correct.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using System;
public void merge()
{
    try
    {
        // string args = "/c ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i mic.wav -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4";
        // string args = "/c ffmpeg - i mic.wav - i example - video.mp4 - c:v copy -vcodec copy final.mp4";
        string args = $"/c ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i mic.wav -shortest out.mp4";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\\Newfolder";
        startInfo.Arguments = args;
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string exx = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try FFmpeg `-map` flag as showed [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/27774/25390).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i mic.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a output.mp4
```

Comment: Shall I need to install ffmpeg other than Accord.Video.FFMPEG?

Comment: As I tested and understood, you should convert audio track to compatible format. So, on wiki some of the mpeg audio formats. I don't really understand how FFmpeg dev libs should be connected on Windows.

Comment: Command prompt says "ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Is there any other way to join wav file with mp4?

Comment: As I understood from the Internet, it's only possible to use FFmpeg through API. No CLI provided though.